# Swift 3 cast UITextField to Int

Tags: swift

I'm receiving a compiler error and I'm not really sure why. I'm sure there is a simple answer for this. I have a core data attribute I'm trying to assign before saving. In my Core Data Property file it's defined as this:

```
@NSManaged public var age: Int32
```

I am using a UIPicker to select it and put it into an inputView. That works fine, so `ageTextField: UITextField!` holds the value. As I try to assign this to the CoreData object just before saving I get the following

```
person.age = ageTextField.text -> Cannot assign String? to Int32.
```

Ok, I understand that, so I cast it

```
person.age = Int(ageTextField.text) -> Value of Optional String not unwrapped...
```

Ok, I get that, so I unwrapped it, it asks to unwrap again and I agree:

```
person.age = Int(ageTextField.text!)! -> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here, just looking over some old Swift 2 code of mine and this worked. This is my first code with Swift 3 though.

Comment: In Xcode 8 you should get rid of stuff like `@NSManaged public var age: Int32`. The core data entities will automatically become classes and their attributes will automatically become properties.

Comment: The actual problem is simply that an Int is not an Int32.

Comment: Hi @matt , thanks for your help. I just used the Create NSManagedObject Subclass. That's the only way i'd come across in my solo learning of swift. What would be a better way. A link is totally cool for me to follow :-)

Comment: Sure, as long as the `@NSManaged public var age: Int32` was generated for you, automatically, you're doing it the modern way.

Comment: @matt Yeah it was. As a side note, is this question really "off-topic as it doesn't seem to be about programming"? I ask you as your rep score signifies you know far more about SO than me. Thank you for your help with my question too

Comment: I suspect that the subset of that "close reason" that the closers have in mind is that the problem is on the level of mere typographical error. To cast something to an Int and try to assign it to an Int32 might reasonably be viewed as trivially silly, making the question a waste of time.

Comment: @matt I suppose yes. I actually thought `Int` and `Int32` were bridged, but looking back through Swift 2 stuff, I can see that the properties used when I generated code last time was identified as `NSNumber` rather than the `Int32`. Hence somewhat of my confusion Thanks again though :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate issue is the use of the wrong type. Use `Int32`, not `Int`. But even once that is fixed, you have lots of other issues.

You should safely unwrap the text and then the attempt to convert the string to an integer.

```
if let text = ageTextField.text, let num = Int32(text) {
    person.age = num
}
```

The use of all of those `!` will cause a crash if the text is `nil` or it contains a value that isn't a valid number. Always use safe unwrapping.

Answer (score 2):

That compiler error is obscure at best and misleading at worst. Change your cast to `Int32`:

```
person.age = Int32(ageTextField.text!)!
```

Also: unless you are absolutely sure that the user will always enter a valid number into the textfield, use optional binding instead of force unwrap:

```
if let text = ageTextField.text,
    let age = Int32(text)
{
    person.age = age
}
```

Comment: FYI - your edit is about using optional binding, not optional chaining.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to unwrap the optional before convert. Make your code safe.

Comment: This won't compile since `Int32(string)` returns an optional. Plus, there is no need to post a duplicate of the other two answers.

Comment: Feel free to delete your answer since it a duplicate as well as incorrect.